# Programmatically using terminal in linux escapes my command

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, ffmpeg, terminal

Using nodeJS exec function which runs my command from a new process overwrites my backslashes which makes my command invalid. How can I prevent this or use a workaround?

I need the final command to look like this:
`...drawtext=text='timestamp \: %{pts \: localtime...`

With that code, `\:` is escaped into `:`.
Using `\\:` is escaped into `\\:` while I'm expecting `\:`

How do I get `...drawtext=text='timestamp \: %{pts \: localtime...` to be ran?

```
// This command works if pasted directly into terminal
const ffmnpegCode = `ffmpeg -i /path/input.mp4 -y -r 25   -ss 0 -to 124 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,drawtext=text='timestamp \: %{pts \: localtime \: 1665679092.241 \: %m-%d-%Y %H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}': x=(w-text_w-10): y=(h-text_h-5): fontsize=45: fontcolor=white@0.9: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.6: fontfile='/path/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'" /path/output.mp4`
const encode = async ffmpegCode => {
    try {
        await execPromise(ffmpegCode);
        return 200
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

JS adds extra `\` which breaks my command

Comment: We'll need more context to help solve this one. How are you using `bash` in this context? You'll need to show us enough code that we can copy/paste into our environment and see the same problem. Read : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the Version information at the top and search for the sections  labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question"  for some ideas on making the smallest test case. You may solve your problem using this technique. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any shell functionality, use [`execFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecfilefile-args-options-callback) or [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) that allow you to specify an array of arguments that are passed directly to exec, so don't require any shell escaping.

```
import { execFile } from 'node:child_process'
const child = execFile('/some/ffmpeg', [
  `-i`, `/path/input.mp4`
  `-vf`, `setsar=1,drawtext=text=timestamp \\: %{pts \\: localtime \\: 1665679092.241 \\: %m-%d-%Y %H\\:%M\\:%S}: x=(w-text_w-10): y=(h-text_h-5)`,
  `/path/output.mp4`,
], console.log)
```

No shell quoting or escaping required, only JS string [escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences) (like `\\` for the command to get a `\`)

Comment: It's displaying the exact same behavior

Comment: Can you add the example command that runs, and the corresponding node code in the question?

Comment: I did and I also found the answer, thanks for the support

Comment: oh wow, that ffmpeg filter syntax definition is something else.  I've updated the plain string escapes anyway. Not sure about the second set of double escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that JS was indeed trying to scape my special characters before running my command so the trick is to use `String.raw()`

`` const command = String.raw`...drawtext=text='timestamp \: %{pts \: localtime...` ``